# Simple Elementary Algebra Equality

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $x,y$ are positive integers and $x\geq1$ and $y\leq1$, then $x+y\geq x\cdot y+1$

Don't have a direction, much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$x,y$ don't have to be integers.

$$x+y\ge xy+1\iff xy-x-y+1=(x-1)(y-1)\le 0$$ and you're given $x\ge 1, y\le 1$.

Consider three cases: $x=1$ or $y=1$ or $\begin{cases}x>1\\ y<1\end{cases}$.

Answer (score 0):

The only positive integer $y \leq 1$ is $y = 1$, and therefore
$$
\begin{array}{rccclr}
x + y &=& x \cdot y + 1 &\geq& x \cdot y + 1, & \qquad\qquad\forall x \geq 1. \tag*{$\blacksquare$}
\end{array}
$$